# How do I come up with a continuous function between two functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

Say $y = 0$ when $x \leq 0$, and $y = 1$ when $x \geq 1$. I want to create a function between these two that still makes everything continuous (continuous at $x = 0$ and $x = 1$) and is monotonically increasing. How can I come up with such a function? Basically, I am trying to find a function that would fit the part in blue (obviously not accurately drawn, but you get the idea):

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason not to connect the "free endpoints" with a line segment? That is,$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & \text{if $x \leq 0$,} \\ x & \text{if $0 < x < 1$,} \\ 1 & \text{if $1 \leq x$.}\end{cases}$$(Ah, this is Herbert Quain's approach.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function looks nice :

$$1-\frac{1}{1+\tan(x\frac{\pi}{2})^3} $$

Comment: How did you come up with this function? On the exam, I have to think of functions like this for different situations so I have to understand how to invent these functions

Comment: The basis is the function $f(x) = 1/(1+h(x))$, with h strictly increasing, $h(0) = 0$ and $h(1) = + \infty$, so we need a function that goes to infinity in finite time, and we have the function tan with this property. But I just verified, it's not so nice, only the first 2 derivatives are zero at 1 and 0. In the ideal world, we woould likee a function with every derivative equal to zero at 0 and 1 to have a $C^{\infty} $ function on the whole

Answer (score 2):

What you draw looks rather like a piece of sine function in between constant "pieces".

Read here (I think it might be quite relevant for you):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function

Answer (score 1):

$x \to x\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]} + \mathbf{1}_{]1, +\infty[}$ does the trick. It is continuous, monotone, and does what you want. However, it is not $\mathcal{C}^1$.

Edit (for if you want a closed-form). Define $f(x) = \frac{x + |x|}{2}$. Then $f$ take the value $0$ if $x \leq 0$ and the value $x$ otherwise. The function 
$$g(x) = f(x) - f(x-1)$$
does the thing.

Comment: Could you explain these notations?

Comment: $\mathbf{1}_A$ is the indicator of the set $A$ : it is a function that takes the value $0$ if $x$ is not in $A$, and $1$ is $x$ is in $A$. So here, $\mathbf{1}_{]1, +\infty[}$ is a function that takes the value $0$ when $x <1$, and then takes the value $1$.